# Memory Caches - Sizes of individual levels

Tags: memory, cpu, cache, cpu-cache

I was just wondering when a program such as CPU-Z or CPU-ID detects your cache levels and it says, for example:

L1 D-Cache Size: 16Kb "x 8" (4 way set associative)
L1 I-Cache Size: 64 Kb "x 4" (2-way set associative)

What does the x 8 and x 4 refer to? Please provide a bit of background if possible. I have a few thoughts on what it could mean but do not want to continue uninformed.

I am interested in this beings how I am already describing the different cache levels of my CPU in a paper.

For those who appreciate visuals, here are images of the program:
http://image.prntscr.com/image/b6d216efd51449efb7da115cea064824.png
http://image.prntscr.com/image/ae3a164e2cbb48a1a192c445d6179c1c.png

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you asking for different ways these are described, or are you looking for an authoritative answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your example of an AMD FX-8350 CPU, which has 8 cores.

A "cache" can be dedicated to a single core, or shared among cores.

When CPU-Z says `x8` it means there are 8 of these caches, so each core gets a  cache for itself.  `x4` means 4 caches, so each of these caches are shared between 2 cores.

If there was a `x2` entry, it would mean 2 caches, each shared among 4 cores.  And the L3 cache is effectively `x1` (CPU-Z just leaves that blank) so this cache is shared among all cores.  I hope this makes sense.  AMD [says it like this](https://cdn.billiger.com/dynimg/pnkpstRd1B-dkkPsXNAzJXt4H9rycHjeBa9LTdXG2DAQ45nx9F4rw8K9aFomZQT0G9iNpKlBLoMz-FHSJJCOKc/AMD-FX-8350-4-0-GHz-Box-FD8350FRHKBOX-Technische-Details-145f6b.pdf):

> - 16-Kbyte 4-Way Associative, Write-through ECC-Protected L1 Data Cache **per Core**
> - 64-Kbyte 2-Way Associative Parity-Protected L1 Instruction Cache **Shared between Two Cores**
> - 1024-Kbyte 16-Way Associative ECC-Protected L2 Cache **Shared between Two Cores**
> - 8192-Kbyte (8-Mbyte) Maximum 64-way Associative Cache **Shared between All Cores** on a Node